# Google Functions Python: how to get a path parameter

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-functions

I have a REST API such as: `/portfolios/{userid}` as the Swagger Path and this points to a google function built using Python 3.

The code is as below:

```
from flask import Flask, request
...
...
def portfolio_routes(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    path = request.path.lower()
    method = request.method.lower()
    ...
```

Assume that the function to execute has been set to: `portfolio_routes`.

If I pass a URL such as: `https:// ..../portfolios/1234`, I get the path as: `portfolios/1234`. Obviously, the **1234** is userid. Like we have @app.routes by placing the userid as , is there a manner we can split the path automatically and get the userid without writing splitting code?

Thanks

Comment: Is this blog of Dustin can help you? https://dev.to/googlecloud/serverless-python-quickstart-with-google-cloud-functions-19bb

Comment: Thanks @guillaumne but this only mentions how to get query string which is documented in Flask using args. What I am trying to do is retrieve path parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about google-cloud-functions, but if is a standard Flask request object the variables passed through url is putted in `view_args`, so you do

```
from flask import Flask, request
...
...
def portfolio_routes(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    path = request.path.lower()
    method = request.method.lower()
    user_id = request.view_args['userId']
    ...
```

In other way, you can do a route split, and compare you masked url(the '/portfolios/{userid}') with the coming url('/portfolios/1234'), your masked url is localized in `request.url_rule` and the coming url in `request.PATH_INFO`

Comment: Thanks @Caio for your response. the view_args does not give `userid` (how will it know). And yes, route split is what I am doing now. Just wondered if there was a internal Flask way of doing it. Thanks